# Overall uncertainty in a set of numbers that are normalised to 1

Tags: standard-error, error-propagation

If I have multiple sets of predictions for $A$, $B$, $C$ subject to the constraint $A+B+C = 1$ I believe I can get standard deviations $\sigma_a$, $\sigma_b$, $\sigma_c$ from the variance over the predictions. Is there any standard approach to combine these standard deviations into an overall uncertainty?

Comment: The overall uncertainty in the sum is zero, by construction.  Please explain, then, what you mean by "overall" uncertainty: what property or characteristic of the predictions do you intend it to represent?

Comment: I want an uncertainty in the ratios i suppose, how sure am I that the ratio is 0.6:0.1:0.3 given the spread of the predictions

Comment: Can you also obtain estimates of the *covariances* of the three estimates?

Comment: yes(ish), I have 5 repeat measurements so can calculate a covariance matrix. I guess the question I want to ask is I have two sets of experiments one that gives 0.6:0.1:0.3 and another that gives 0.2:0.5:0.3 for example say the repeats for the first vary a lot but the repeats for the second do not vary much can I produce a single number to capture this

Comment: I get a strong sense that your question would work better by stating what data you have and how and why you are analyzing them.  In its present abstract form it's unlikely to suggest useful or appropriate procedures.

Comment: I am looking at chemical reactions, depending on the conditions I pick when I mix my reactants the resulting mixture after the reaction has different ratios of products controlled by the conditions due to interplay between kinetics and side reactions. I want to be able to set conditions such that repeat measurements reliably produce the same ratios of the products. I am trying to conduct a black box optimisation to find such consistent regions in the conditions space. This uncertainty number would be the black box output that I want to minimize.

Comment: @whuber now I think I get it more, the true variance in the sum is always zero due to the constraint as the covariance terms always cancel. Consequently I think either the trace or the spectral norm of the covariance matrix is the right direction

Comment: If that's the case, then the trace is particularly simple: it's the sum of the three variances.